# Motion for moving to non-top-level Python function definition

Tags: cursor-movement

I'm looking for something like `[[` (or `[]`, `]]`, `][`) that works with non-top-level function definitions instead of the next line with a top-level class or function definition on the first character.

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def baz(self): #jump from here...
    pass

  def box(self): #... to here without searching or...
    pass

biz = 123

def bar(): #... without going straight here
  pass
```

It seems like, by default, vim ignores variable definitions and other things that start on the first character of a line, but when I'm looking through class methods, my only recourse is to search for `def XYZ`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`]m` (and `[m`) seem to fit the bill. From `:help ]m`:

```
                        *]m*
]m          Go to [count] next start of a method (for Java or
            similar structured language).  When not before the
            start of a method, jump to the start or end of the
            class.  When no '{' is found after the cursor, this is
            an error.  |exclusive| motion. {not in Vi}
```

Simply pressing `]m` will jump to the exact place you want to.